# Problem updating a resource array due to node single thread concurrency

Tags: node.js, postgresql, concurrency, typeorm, single-threaded

Tables:

| users | user_category | categories |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user_id (PK) | user_id (PK) | category_id (PK) |
| name | category_id (PK) | name |

I'm having problems with concurrency on node, I'll describe an example to reproduce the error I have:

When receiving 5 requests in parallel to perform a PUT on the same existing user and their categories:

PUT users/userId123

**body**

```
{
    "name": "other name"
    "categories" : [
    "categoryId123",
    "categoryId456",
    "categoryId789",
    ]
}
```

Upon receiving this payload in a simulation, first a **DELETE** query is performed on **user_category** and then an **INSERT** on **user_category** to insert the new categories.

It turns out that as the node is a single thread, the main thread competes, and when performing 5 identical requests in parallel, it is happening to perform two DELETES of two different requests and then the 2 INSERTs, which will generate a primary key error in the table **user_category**, I already tried to use a transaction for these two queries, but the error still occurs, blocking the main thread until doing these two operations is not an option defied the loss in performance.

**Attempt-1**

Below is an excerpt from UserController code that does this

```
if (Array.isArray(user.categories)) {
      await userCategoriesRepository.deleteHardByUserId(user.userId)

      const userCategories = []
      for (const categoryId of user.categories) {
          userCategories.push({userId: user.userId, categoryId})
      }
      await userCategoriesRepository.save(userCategories)
}
```

UserRepository:

```
  save (userCategories: ICreateUserCategoryDTO[]): Promise<void> {
    try {
      return this.repository.insert(userCategories)
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error(error)
    }
  }

  deleteHardByUserId (userId: string): Promise<void> {
    try {
      return this.repository.delete({ userId })
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error(error)
    }
  }
```

**Attempt-2 (Transaction)**
Below is an excerpt from UserController code that does this

```
if (Array.isArray(user.categories)) { 
      const userCategories = []
      for (const categoryId of user.categories) {
          userCategories.push({userId: user.userId, categoryId})
      }

      await userCategoriesRepository.updateWithTransaction(userId, userCategories)
}
```

UserRepository:

```
async updateWithTransaction (userId: string, userCategories: ICreateUserCategoryDTO[]) {
    try {
      return getManager().transaction(async transaction => {
        await transaction.delete(UserCategory, { userId })
        await transaction.insert(UserCategory, userCategories)
      })
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error(error)
    }
  }
```

**QUERY LOGGING**

- case: 1 request (SUCESS)

  query: START TRANSACTION // REQUEST 1

  query: DELETE FROM "user_category" WHERE "user_id" = $1 -- PARAMETERS: ["userId123"] // REQUEST 1

  query: INSERT INTO "user_category"("user_id", "category_id") VALUES ($1, $2) -- PARAMETERS: ["userId123", "categoryId123"] // REQUEST 1

  query: COMMIT // REQUEST 1
- case: 2 or more requests parallel (ERROR PK)

  query: START TRANSACTION // REQUEST 1

  query: DELETE FROM "user_category" WHERE "user_id" = $1 -- PARAMETERS: ["userId123"] // REQUEST 1

  query: START TRANSACTION // REQUEST 2

  query: DELETE FROM "user_category" WHERE "user_id" = $1 -- PARAMETERS: ["userId123"] // REQUEST 2

  query: INSERT INTO "user_category"("user_id", "category_id") VALUES ($1, $2) -- PARAMETERS: ["userId123", "categoryId123"] // REQUEST 1

  query: COMMIT // REQUEST 1

  query: INSERT INTO "user_category"("user_id", "category_id") VALUES ($1, $2), ($3, $4) -- PARAMETERS: ["userId123", "categoryId123", "userId123", "categoryId456"] // REQUEST 2 --> PK ERROR

  query: COMMIT // REQUEST 2

**Details:**

- node 16.13.1
- typeorm 4.3.2
- pg 8.4.0
- npm 8.3.0
- Postgres database 13.2

Comment: This is just a design that is subject to race conditions as you're trying to do multiple operations on potentially stale data with multiple database operations.  It has nothing to do with nodejs single threaded nature.  You will need to use concurrency features in your database to code this properly without race conditions.

Comment: Hello @jfriend00 , could you show me an example of how it would be done in this case? thanks.

Comment: I don't know the tools in your specific database.  FYI, I suspect the solution may also extend into where `user.categories` comes from.

Comment: For someone who does know your database to help, you will probably need to show the actual database calls.  This code appears to be some wrapper around the actual database calls.  And, please show all database calls being used in the request handler.

Comment: @jfriend00, I updated the question, the error always happens in simulate parallel calls that dispute the principle thread to perform an update on one user, I understand that I must perform in a single query this update of a user's categories, but I have not yet found the appropriate solution.

Comment: What postgresql library are you using?  I can't find references to the database calls you're using and don't see any sql statements.  Sql BEGIN, COMMIT and ROLLBACK are for transactions in sql, right?

Comment: Right at the end of the question, the technologies used are specified, I'm using typeorm 4.3.2

Comment: One suggestion is to change `return getManager().transaction(async transaction => {` to `return getManager().transaction("SERIALIZABLE", async transaction => {`.  I cannot find what the default is if you don't pass the isolation level when using postgresql so better to specify the tightest control and see if that helps.  See doc [here](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/transactions).  Transaction support when using a generic layer like typeorm depends upon the individual database driver.

Comment: I've already tried to perform this isolation, but the result is still the same, when receiving requests in parallel for the same user, the delete query from request-1 is executed, then the delete query from request-2, and after the queries insert from request-1 and insert from request-2, with that we have the primary key errors, when executed with a single request, all the attempts I mentioned in the question work well.

Comment: @jfriend00, I added the query log in the question for better understanding of the problem.

Comment: What do you expect to happen here?  You're submitting two contending changes to the database very close in time.

Comment: Also, why are you deleting the user and then re-inserting it, rather than just updating the existing user?  That would not cause a conflict in the scenario you show.  And, most databases have an ability to insert/modify depending upon whether it already exists.  The query log is very useful.

Comment: Look up optimistic concurrency. Bottom line is even with transactions, you'll need to handle failures when one of the invocations loses the race.

Comment: @jfriend00, I'm updating the user's categories, so I understand that I must delete all of them and insert them again, because the way for a user to delete an associated category is by sending the array without it, only with the ones he wants to remain.

Comment: @StephenCleary, I understand, but I would like to know what would be the best solution for this type of situation, so that the final result is a mirror of the last request received by the API.

Comment: OK, then use optimistic concurrency and resolve conflicts using last-in-wins.